# fastest way to find all numbers between target numbers

Tags: r

Given numbers in a vector (e.g. 1 5 10 12), I'm looking for those numbers in the vector that fall between a number range of my choice (e.g. c(9, 11)). I expect `vec = c(10)` to be returned in this small example.

Here's a larger MWE below where I use `dplyr::between` to subset the relevant values...However, I'm looking for a faster way to do this (that does not use parallelization as a solution). Let me know if I can explain something better.

```
# Data
set.seed(1)
targets <- sort(sample(1:1e8, 1e7, replace=FALSE))
vec <- c(1345706, 1405938)

# Function
dplyr_between <- function(vec, targets) {
            require(dplyr)
            targets <- targets[dplyr::between(targets, vec[1], vec[2])]
            return(targets)
        }

test <- dplyr_between(vec, targets)
# 1345732 1345761 1345779 1345780 1345797
```

*Edit* Add function based on comment using `x < max & x > min` (since deleted)

```
# More Functions
base_compare <- function(vec, targets) {
            targets <- targets[targets < vec[2] & targets > vec[1]]
            return(targets)
        }

base_compare(vec, targets)
# 1345732 1345761 1345779 1345780 1345797
```

*Edit* using `data.table::inrange` from @docendo

```
# inrange function
dt_inrange <- function(vec, targets) {
            require(data.table)
            targets <- targets[inrange(targets, vec[1], vec[2])]
            return(targets)
        }

dt_inrange(vec, targets)
# 1345732 1345761 1345779 1345780 1345797
```

Benchmark

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(dplyr_between(vec, targets), base_compare(vec, targets), dt_inrange(vec, targets), times=10L)
# Unit: milliseconds
                       # expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max
# dplyr_between(vec, targets) 265.5192 283.5998 296.0947 296.7552 309.4403 323.3634
#  base_compare(vec, targets) 303.4629 317.8389 343.6311 343.3765 354.6891 427.1962
#    dt_inrange(vec, targets) 129.3800 131.1634 142.8658 144.4569 149.3728 164.5824
 # neval
    # 10
    # 10
    # 10
```

Thanks!

Comment: @MikeH. it's not faster unfortunately

Comment: This is faster on my laptop: `library(data.table); targets[inrange(targets, vec[1], vec[2])]`

Comment: @docendodiscimus yes, significantly faster, thanks! I'll still wait for other solutions in case a faster one shows up. Would you like to post as a potential solution...if yours is still the fastest, I'd be happy to accept as an answer.

Comment: Btw u dont need to reassign inside the function and the return if u also leave out the return statement. Plus, when comparing u don’t need to load the package each time.

Comment: You can post it yourself, I don’t have time now

Comment: @docendodiscimus I'm aware of your points, thanks

Comment: Good suggestion @Gregor, edited...

Comment: Also, I believe none of the solutions so far use the fact that `targets` is sorted. If you use keyed data.table, that will certainly be faster. Otherwise in rcpp it would be easy to take advantage of that (if it is indeed a reliable property). You just need to find the first `target[i] > vec[1]` and go until you find the first `target[j] > vec[2]` and then you can stop.

Comment: @Gregor what you're saying makes sense, but I don't know how to implement those solutions you're describing (appreciate the ninja edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple Rcpp implementation:

C++ code in temp.cpp"

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<int> betweenRcpp(IntegerVector vec, int lower, int upper) {
  std::vector<int> ret;
  for(int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++) {
    if((vec[i] > lower) & (vec[i] < upper)) {
      ret.push_back(vec[i]);
    } else if(vec[i] >= upper) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return ret;
}
```

R code:

```
library(Rcpp)
library(microbenchmark)
setwd("~/Desktop")
# Data
set.seed(1)
targets <- sort(sample(1:1e8, 1e7, replace=FALSE))
vec <- c(1345706, 1405938)

# Function
dplyr_between <- function(vec, targets) {
  require(dplyr)
  targets <- targets[dplyr::between(targets, vec[1], vec[2])]
  return(targets)
}

sourceCpp("temp.cpp")

test <- dplyr_between(vec, targets)
test2 <- betweenRcpp(targets, vec[1], vec[2])

microbenchmark(dplyr_between(vec, targets), betweenRcpp(targets, vec[1], vec[2]), times=10)


Unit: microseconds
                                 expr       min        lq        mean      median        uq        max neval cld
          dplyr_between(vec, targets) 72066.027 77809.681 108023.3793 103723.4075 125280.89 173892.552    10   b
 betweenRcpp(targets, vec[1], vec[2])   439.124   464.475    502.7439    481.8025    543.12    594.578    10  a
```

Test equality between solutions:

```
all(test == test2)
```

Comment: Measured in microseconds, do I win? :P

Comment: Nice one! You win unless someone ambitious implements a binary search rcpp solution to find the min and max :)

Comment: Yes, I doubt I'll find faster than this. I'll try to implement your code for my case now.

Comment: Btw, you can do: `sample(1e8, 1e7, replace=F)` which is about 30% faster to generate your MWE.

Comment: Also, if your real data isn't pre-sorted, it's faster to do not sort your data and use a implementation that doesn't assume sort.

Answer (score 1):

Since your data is sorted, you can use a keyed data table. I equate pre-sortind the data with pre-keying the data table, so the time to create the key is not part of the benchmark. I also removed the cruft from `dt_inrange` so the comparison can focus on the task at hand.

```
key_dt = data.table(targets, key = "targets")
# note that `targets` does not need to be sorted beforehand
# the key = "targets" will sort it as the table is created.
# You can also use `setkey` to add a key to an existing data table.

dt_inrange <- function(vec, targets) {
            targets[inrange(targets, vec[1], vec[2])]
        }

key_dt_inrange <- function(vec, target_dt) {
  target_dt[inrange(targets, vec[1], vec[2]), targets]
}
print(microbenchmark(
  dt_inrange(vec, targets),
  key_dt_inrange(vec, key_dt),
  times = 10
), signif = 3, order = "mean")
# Unit: milliseconds
#                         expr  min   lq     mean median    uq   max neval cld
#  key_dt_inrange(vec, key_dt) 47.5 47.9 54.75557   50.4  52.2  98.6    10   a
#     dt_inrange(vec, targets) 48.8 49.8 99.18932   60.4 185.0 219.0    10   a
```

For whatever reason, it looks like unkeyed method has some right skew, with the mean 50% larger than the median, but this is prevented in the keyed data table method.

Comment: Can you explain the concept of keyed data tables?  I don't understand the difference between those two methods.

Comment: I can give you a link to the data.table vignette, [Keys and fast binary search based subset](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-keys-fast-subset.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
microbenchmark(db = {
    x = findInterval(vec, targets)
    targets[(x[1]+1):x[2]]
},
dplyr_between(vec, targets))
#Unit: milliseconds
#                        expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
#                          db  51.02101  58.43651  78.81237  70.51761  79.58609 410.3919   100  a 
# dplyr_between(vec, targets) 127.03341 148.65899 177.43284 156.37937 170.22009 431.5442   100   b


identical({x = findInterval(vec, targets)
          targets[(x[1]+1):x[2]]}, test)
#[1] TRUE
```