# R: fast counting of rows that match vector of conditional

Tags: r, data.table, vectorization

I have data

```
dt <- data.table(beg=as.POSIXct(c("2018-01-01 01:01:00","2018-01-01 01:05:00","2018-01-01 01:08:00")), end=as.POSIXct(c("2018-01-01 01:10:00","2018-01-01 01:10:00","2018-01-01 01:10:00")))
> dt
                   beg                 end
1: 2018-01-01 01:01:00 2018-01-01 01:10:00
2: 2018-01-01 01:05:00 2018-01-01 01:10:00
3: 2018-01-01 01:08:00 2018-01-01 01:10:00
```

and

```
times <- seq(from=min(dt$beg),to=max(dt$end),by="mins")
```

and I would like to count, as efficiently as possible, for each time in `times` how many intervals in `df` include the time.

I understand that

```
count <- NA
for(i in 1:length(times)){
   count[i] <- sum(dt$beg<times[i] & dt$end>times[i])
}
```

would yield the solution

```
> data.table(times, count)
                   time count
 1: 2018-01-01 01:01:00     0
 2: 2018-01-01 01:02:00     1
 3: 2018-01-01 01:03:00     1
 4: 2018-01-01 01:04:00     1
 5: 2018-01-01 01:05:00     1
 6: 2018-01-01 01:06:00     2
 7: 2018-01-01 01:07:00     2
 8: 2018-01-01 01:08:00     2
 9: 2018-01-01 01:09:00     3
10: 2018-01-01 01:10:00     0
```

but I am wondering whether there is a more time-efficient solution, e.g., using data.table.

Comment: I asked a similar question, which might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47019127/fastest-way-to-find-all-numbers-between-target-numbers. Look at the `Rcpp` solution although there is a `data.table` solution as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be a solution

```
times = as.data.table(times)
ans = dt[times, .(x.beg, x.end, i.x),on = .(beg < x , end > x),allow.cartesian = TRUE]
ans[,sum(!is.na(x.end)), by = .(i.x)]
                    i.x V1
 1: 2018-01-01 01:01:00  0
 2: 2018-01-01 01:02:00  1
 3: 2018-01-01 01:03:00  1
 4: 2018-01-01 01:04:00  1
 5: 2018-01-01 01:05:00  1
 6: 2018-01-01 01:06:00  2
 7: 2018-01-01 01:07:00  2
 8: 2018-01-01 01:08:00  2
 9: 2018-01-01 01:09:00  3
10: 2018-01-01 01:10:00  0
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! But it gives me an error: ` "logical error. i is not a data.table, but 'on' argument is provided."`

Comment: `times` must be data.table, e. g. convert it via `dt.times <- data.table(times = times)` and use `dt.times` instead of `times` in the first row...

Comment: You can use a list instead of a data.table. Also, `by=.EACHI` helps: `dt[.(t = times), on=.(beg < t, end > t), .N, by=.EACHI]`

Comment: Works much for efficiently than the for-loop. Cheers!